# Dividing or splitting polygon to smaller polygons with PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

I have list of points of a polygon. I have created a polygon in QGIS with the following code:

```
area2_pologon = {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[51.4763461, 35.7901169], [51.4751952, 35.7888939], [51.4740016, 35.7876951], [51.4733766, 35.7871033], [51.47316469999999, 35.786918299999996], [51.4727141, 35.7866964], [51.4719765, 35.7864984], [51.4714347, 35.7863722], [51.4708983, 35.7862547], [51.4704798, 35.7860502], [51.4700936, 35.785367], [51.4682107, 35.78154609999999], [51.4666121, 35.7780645], [51.4642947, 35.775348699999995], [51.4632325, 35.7741936], [51.4622669, 35.7731204], [51.4601962, 35.7707265], [51.45786809999999, 35.7679844], [51.45659139999999, 35.7664958], [51.4560442, 35.7658429], [51.4554541, 35.763892799999994], [51.4554363, 35.763792], [51.4553379, 35.7634323], [51.4552627, 35.7632478], [51.4546602, 35.7616554], [51.4543705, 35.7610547], [51.4538233, 35.7604105], [51.4526364, 35.755246], [51.45258969999999, 35.755031699999996], [51.4525251, 35.7547426], [51.4525036, 35.75464509999999], [51.4522676, 35.7535759], [51.4512699, 35.7529055], [51.449617599999996, 35.7518954], [51.4490137, 35.7516396], [51.4491411, 35.75117809999999], [51.4491801, 35.75096009999999], [51.44920449999999, 35.7503434], [51.449504899999994, 35.7483495], [51.4495156, 35.7478183], [51.44939759999999, 35.7471478], [51.4489316, 35.7463386], [51.4489792, 35.7462074], [51.448593, 35.7456327], [51.447335, 35.7436038], [51.4471994, 35.7433432], [51.4471365, 35.743016], [51.4468918, 35.74203489999999], [51.4504679, 35.7417598], [51.45364899999999, 35.7414594], [51.4569642, 35.7411546], [51.4578225, 35.7411111]]]}
A = np.array(area2_pologon["coordinates"])

polygon_coordinates = []
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    for j in range(A.shape[1]):
        x = A[i,j][0]
        y = A[i,j][1]
        polygon_coordinates.append(QgsPoint(x, y))
        # print "x: {} , y: {}".format(A[i,j][0],A[i,j][1])


# create a polygon        
gPolygon = QgsGeometry.fromPolygon([polygon_coordinates])
# check whether is polygon or not
print gPolygon.wkbType() == QGis.WKBPolygon
# extract information from polygon
info_polygon = gPolygon.asPolygon()
print info_polygon
```

Now I want to split this polygon to smaller polygons so that I can get list of points of any smaller polygon.

How do I perform this?

Comment: With this code you produce a polygon in Iran area. For dividing it you need a process. What are criteria for dividing? (how many polygons?, equal areas?).